# Selenium send keys sending too fast

Tags: python, selenium

I'm testing a login on a site that has a standard username entry and a hidden password input. I select the username and send the string. I'm unable to select the password box because `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible` so instead I do this:

```
login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/input[1]')
login.send_keys(foo)
login.send_keys(Keys.TAB + bar + Keys.ENTER)
```

This never works, the password is 10 characters long and it never manages to get all 10 in the password box.

I had thought I could `sleep(1)` between sending the keys, but due to the nature of the hidden field that isn't possible.

How can I get past this issue, either by selecting the password field directly, or allowing the string to be sent in full?

*EDIT*

The website is the sports betting section of [this](http://www.bet365.com) site. For those of you unable to view because of jurisdiction reasons, I'll provide a HTML sample of it when I'm back home.

Comment: Selenium not allow to click/sendkey on a not visible element on page, you can try driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", <the password element>, <the password string>)  driver.execute_script() will inject the javascript in first parameter into browser and execute it on browser.

Comment: How is a user supposed to enter their password if it is hidden? I think you are looking at the wrong password field. Share a link to the page or the relevant HTML.

Comment: agree with Jeffc, confirm you not use wrong element firslty, Our automation should more close to user experience when simulator user operation, we not encourage to use  execute_script() in such situation. It should be your last option.

Comment: @JeffC added the page in question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the element to be visible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def wait_for_element_visible_by_css_selector(self, css, timeout=20):
    '''
    Wait for an element to be visible.
    This is used for example for a drop-down selector to wait for the list to show up
    :param css: the CSS pattern of the element to watch
    :param timeout: time to wait for it.
    '''
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
      EC.visibility_of(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css))
    )
```

I use this function as a helper as part of the testCase. So you'll need to adjust to provide the proper `self` from yours.

Then just pass it the css selector of your item.

```
wait_for_element_visible_by_css_selector('input')
```

you can obviously adapt this to using xpath if you prefer.

You can also use other types of waits:

```
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css))
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do a few things on pages that are a bit flakey with the timing. First make sure i wait for the page to load, then send the keys, then sleep, then click.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
x.send_keys(something)
Thread.sleep(500)
submit.click
```

Comment: any kind of sleep is bad practice with selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I think much of the issue is how you are trying to sendkeys to the password field using TAB. There's no need to rely on tabbing to the right element, just grab the one you want. Also, using XPath with more than probably 4-5 levels deep to find the element (especially one that starts at the HTML tag) is not a good practice. It will be very prone to changes in the page and will break. I would do something like the below.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hm-Login_UserNameWrapper > input.hm-Login_InputField").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hm-Login_PasswordWrapper > input.hm-Login_InputField")).send_keys(username)
```

There is an input field marked as type=password

```
<input type="password" class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden ">
```

but it is hidden so is not the one that a user would type into. The selectors I specified above were tested and worked.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
login.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
login.send_keys(<password>)
submit.click()
```